# Singleton as dependency

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, yaml

I have a library that I am trying to build in a Symfony2 bundle and one of the third-party libraries I am using is a singleton.  I need to inject this as a dependency on a class, but I am unsure how.

I have to run SomeClass::create('StringForManip') as a dependency

Comment: Take a look at how to configure the dependency injection container to use a factory: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Answer (score 0):

You have just to combine them into bundle. When you do it, use proper namespace, and everything should work. Focus on namespacing.